# Is it possible to recover data using a USB to IDE/SATA adapter?

Tags: data-recovery, sata-to-usb

I have a [Gembird IDE/S-ATA2 to USB adapter](https://gembird.com/item.aspx?id=4178) and I was wondering if it is possible to use it for deleted files recovery from a notebook SATA hard-drive?

Is the data recovery process sending some low level commands to the hard drive which might be lost if transmitted via USB?

Comment: Yes, of course.  I have done it many times. For a laptop drive (2.5), you don't even need all of that.  A simple 11USD adapter [like this one](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B011M8YACM?ref=ppx_yo2_dt_b_product_details&th=1) will do the trick.  Ignore that it says SSD, the adapter is the same and I own two of them.   I would *suggest* that you first copy the drive to another drive via `dd` (or similar) and only attempt recovery on the copied drive.  Every time you access the failing drive, things will probably get worse.

Comment: The answer is a solid: Maybe! All SATA to USB adapters do is connect a typically hard drive to a computer via USB. If the data is on the drive, recoverable and readable then yes, you can use this tool to connect the drive to a system to recover data. But there are no “low level commands” that would be lost if the data is sent via USB. Past that, as it stands this question doesn’t have enough details to really allow someone to provide a solid answer. If you can add details such as the exact make and model of the drive, what OS you are on and what is the context of the deletion that can help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it is possible to use it for deleted files recovery from a notebook SATA hard-drive?

This might depend on the tool, but yes, it should work the same as with a directly connected disk.

> Is the data recovery process sending some low level commands to the hard-drive which might be lost if transmitted via USB?

Generally, no. Data recovery software typically just reads data sectors the same way the OS would – it only uses different approaches at finding data that might still be there (e.g. a photo was "deleted", but the actual JPEG data is still there, it's only not attached to a folder anymore).

While it is true that there are many commands that won't work through many USB adapters<sup>1</sup>, none of those commands are generally used for data recovery. In particular, there is no "undo write" or "recover sector" command in disks – once a sector is overwritten, it is overwritten.<sup>2</sup>

That being said, some USB adapters don't deal well with *damaged* disks, e.g. if some sectors are physically almost unreadable, the disk might still keep retrying but the adapter might already decide to "give up". (This may confuse tools like "ddrescue" which try to copy partially damaged disks.) It is often useful to have several adapters that are built with different controller chips.

On the other hand, beware of adapters that translate *too much* – there exist some which actually remap sectors to a different size (making a 512b disk appear like a 4K one); when connected through such an adapter, the data is *technically* still there, but at completely different offsets, so the OS wouldn't even recognize completely intact filesystems.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is partly because USB storage devices talk SCSI, not ATA, so the adapter has to translate. (Moreover, "regular" Mass Storage devices speak a *very* limited subset, while the newer UASP standard is more flexible.)

Many ATA commands have SCSI equivalents and can be translated or at least tunnelled, but a lot of cheap USB-SATA<sup>3</sup> adapters don't actually bother to translate all of them – only the most common ones (read, write, identify disk, read ATA SMART data).

As an example, a lot of USB-SATA adapters won't support issuing TRIM commands to SSDs, even though there *is* a direct SCSI equivalent and a translation could be performed.

<sup>2</sup> With lower-density disks, overwritten data could potentially be retrieved using expensive physical inspection (hence the "3-pass DoD wipe" and similar), but nowadays that's pretty unlikely to work.

<sup>3</sup> The official [name](https://sata-io.org/developers/sata-naming-guidelines) is either "SATA" or "Serial ATA".

Comment: thank you for your input. Can you recommend us what USB -> SATA adapter technologies to avoid - so that we skip using the lazy ones (which give up prematurely) and the ones which translate/remap too much (this are some just dumb examples: don't use USB x.y because it needs translation; use older/newer versions than x.y; the Z ssd/hdd manufacturer is not using the full standard ABC so remapping is happening when using it's products)